# AngularJs: Detect Click on Parent scope from isolated directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

Hi I have an isolated directive. I want to detect if the scope has been clicked on using `$scope.$parent` object. Is this possible. I am trying to listen to a click event on a parent scope using the scope object variable...is this possible?

Comment: is it possible to make a plunker

Comment: Why don't just pass that object from parent scope to the isolated scope?

Comment: @neptune how do i do that?

Comment: @flexxxit see here: https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope

Answer (score 0):

In this particular instance, you would want to use $scope.$on to listen to the event occurring.

Todd Motto provides a great example to understand this in more detail.

https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/